# Access is denied while processing web.config with Sql Server Compact

Tags: web-hosting, windows

I just deployed an ASP.NET MVC3 site to a new hoster. It is using the Plesk Control panel. The site is using Sql Server Compact 4.0 and [EricEJ's Sql Server Compact Membership and Role provider](http://sqlcemembership.codeplex.com/).

When trying to access the site, I'm getting an access is denied error on the web.config file where I add the SqlCeMembershipProvider:

> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
>
> Source Error:
>
> ```
> Line 31:         <clear /> 
> Line 32:         <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" /> 
> Line 33:         <add name="SqlCeMembershipProvider" type="ErikEJ.SqlCeMembershipProvider, ErikEJ.SqlCeMembership" connectionStringName="SqlCeServices" applicationName="/" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="true" passwordFormat="Hashed" writeExceptionsToEventLog="false" /> 
> Line 34:       </providers> 
> Line 35:     </membership>
> ```

The SqlCeServices connection string is configured like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="SqlCeServices" connectionString="data source=|DataDirectory|\SqlCeAspnetdb.sdf" />
</connectionStrings>
```

When I go to the "File Manager" in the Plesk control panel, and click on "change permissions" for the "App_Data" folder, all the users (that I can configure) have write and modify permissions:

[image: permissions for app_data]

Although, when I click the "advanced" button, this is what I see:

[image: advanced permissions for app_data]

The entry on the bottom for "Plesk IIS WP User (IWPD_321)" has all the permissions. But apparently, there are 2 additional entries for that same user on top. These don't have write permissions, but anything I change for those 2 doesn't get saved. When I come back to the screen, they are again as shown (without write permission).

I'm not sure what I can do, or what I have to ask the helpdesk of the hoster to get this solved (they don't seem to have experience with Sql Server Compact).

I tried removing the lines from web.config where the SqlServerCe Connection string is used, and then I can run the site, but I can't create (register) users or roles, as I don't have a Sql Server database.

Any suggestions on what to try next?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. I needed to add **"Read/Execute" rights to the \bin folder and all its child objects** for the "Plesk IIS WP User (IWPD_321)" user.

The \bin folder is where the Sql Server Compact binaries reside.

Guess I was focusing on the \App_Data folder too much...

Comment: Thanks!!!! after 100 (ok, 12) tries this is the one that works!